# App Signing & Testing and Publishing Options

Tags: android

I am about to write an App which is customized to Macau, a city in Southern China. I am experiencing some uncertainties and would like to seek help from the fellow developers.

I have checked with Android Dev Guide and found out that we have gotta sign the App with self-generated key or a digital certificate issued from Certificate Authority. May I know whether there are any differences in the user experience when downloading and using the App for self-generated key or digital cert from CA? I heard that Symbian Apps would display alert message like "This App is untrusted" if the App is not formally verified. I do not want this to happen in my App, and I am worried about other tiny differences.

Moreover, I would like to ask about the requirements for digital certificate for signing the App. Is there any specification? Must the key be a .keystore file for signing? I am thinking about applying one from the Post Office for signing, but am worried whether it works.

From the Google Dev Guide, it says we need to plug the Android device to the computer using USB and run the App and perform testing using the computer. May I know more about the testing procedures from the experienced? After this debugging process how can I test the App on a standalone Android phone just like using the App normally? Can I simply sign the App with debug key in the debug mode and use it on the device? Must the device be developer device or Nexus One for performing testing?

If I publish the App to the Web server, i.e. users can download the file and use my file, would my source code be leaked out and get accessed by other people?

Last but not least, as I am developing the free App in Macau, I was stuck when I saw that Macau is not on the developer location list. I wonder whether I can publish my App on the Android Market. When I settle the Google Checkout payment, which option should I choose as my location, as neither China nor Macau is on the list. Should I choose "Hong Kong", my neighbouring city, or simply click "US" for convenience? Can the Android users in Macau download my App from the Android Market? (I cannot see Macau on the supported distribution location list...)

I would really appreciate it if you could kindly answer my loads of questions. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

That's way to many questions for one post, but I'll take a shot at a few.

You must sign your app using a keystore.  It *should* be one you created, but hey, that is your choice.  Any app not downloaded from the market is considered "untrusted" and users will receive that error upon installing it.

As far as debugging, you can debug on an emulator and/or a device (phone).  Most people will recommend both.  Information about how to get started can be found on the [Android Development website.](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)  More specifically, you can try [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html)
 or [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html).

You can sign the app with a debug key if you [setup USB debugging](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) on the phone.

You publish apps as .apk files, which is complied code, not source.  Even then it is hackable, just like anything else.

Comment: May I know what keystore means? Is it a file extension type (.keystore)? Can the keys issued by the Certification Authority meet this requirement and be used for signing the key? I am worried that the cert cannot be used after paying the CA for the digital certificate... 

Do you mean that as long as I upload the app onto Android Market, it must be trusted and would not experience any error message? So how can I make the app trusted when I publish the app to the Web server rather than the Android Market? 

Thanks. :)